# Why are the properties of this object undefined? Javascript

Tags: javascript

Attribute is an object in this form:

```
   var attribute = {
    AttributeId: attributeId,
    EntityId: entityId,
    AttributeDBName: attributeDbName,
    AttributeDisplayName: attributeDisplayName,
    IsSearchable: isSearchable,
    IsDeleted: isDeleted,
    IsVisible: isVisible,
    AttributeTypeId: attributeTypeId,
    Description: description,
    IsSystem: isSystem,
    IsActive: isActive,
    IsUnique: isUnique,
    IsRequired: isRequired,
    IsPersistent: isPersistent,
    DefaultValue: defaultValue
};
```

That attribute then gets passed to this function along with the ID of a grid:

```
function AddAttributeToGrid(attribute, gridId) {

    console.log(attribute); //Works! Displays the attribute.

    var id = a.attributeId;

    console.log(id);//UNDEFINED? WHAT?   

}
```

If I create a global variable (let's call it 'tempAttribute') and set it inside of AddAttributeToGrid, like so:

```
 function AddAttributeToGrid(attribute, gridId) {
    tempAttribute = attribute
}
```

I can then access the properties of tempAttribute...

Why can I not get the data from the properties? 
What is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property of `attribute` is `AttributeId`, not `attributeId`.

JavaScript is case sensitive.

But this assumes you initialized your object with a defined `attributeId` to start with. This is not clear in your code.

Comment: Omg. I can't believe that I missed that... LMFAO!
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

i think you have

```
var id = a.attributeId;
```

instead of

```
var id = attribute.AttributeId;
```

inside the `AddAttributeToGrid` function definition

Comment: Close :) Turns out it was just a damn capitol letter instead of lowercase!